# problem with webview in android

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview in my app. I can see the title of the website on the title bar (I have custom title bar). However, i dont see anything in the view - the website is not viewable :(.. any suggestions ? Here's the code:

```
public class WebViewer extends Activity {

WebView webView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewer);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    String url = "http://www.google.com";

    final TextView title=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text_view_success3);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            title.setText("Loading...");
            WebViewer.this.setProgress(progress * 100);

            if(progress == 100)
            title.setText(webView.getTitle());
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

Comment: apparently moving the webview.loadURL(url) above some other code line solved it. really dont know why ! :(

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
```

This isn't needed. shouldOverrideUrlLoading is called before the url is loaded to give you a chance to handle loading yourself. What you're doing is loading the url over and over.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: well, i think we need that so that whenever we click on a link, it doesnt open in the default browser !

Comment: Calling loadUrl will cause shouldOverrideUrlLoading to be called. So what your code was doing is calling loadUrl, handling shouldOverideUrlLoading, then reloading the webpage.